# In CSS display:table, how do I maintain consistent cell widths?

Tags: css, width

I'm using pure CSS to create table layouts and neither my rows nor cells are behaving like tr or td elements.

The results seem to be that cells do not keep a consistent width and rows seem to have a `float: left` behavior when they should be `display: block`

This seems to work OK without the anchor tags... why?

```css
.livesearchtable {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.livesearchrow {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  width: 100%;
}

.livesearchcell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="livesearchtable">
  <a href="../something.php">
    <div class="livesearchrow">
      <div class="livesearchcell">1</div>
      <div class="livesearchcell">Some text thats long enough to make a difference</div>
      <div class="livesearchcell">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="../something.php">
    <div class="livesearchrow">
      <div class="livesearchcell">2</div>
      <div class="livesearchcell">short</div>
      <div class="livesearchcell"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Take class 'livesearchrow' and set it as class for a tags. Delete divs with 'livesearchrow' class. Now a.livesearchrow is table-row and divs inside it are table-cells.

```
<div class="livesearchtable">
  <a href="../something.php" class="livesearchrow">
    <div class="livesearchcell">1</div>
    <div class="livesearchcell">Some text thats long enough to make a difference</div>
    <div class="livesearchcell">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </a>
  <a href="../something.php" class="livesearchrow">
    <div class="livesearchcell">2</div>
    <div class="livesearchcell">short</div>
    <div class="livesearchcell"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: in case you are still worried why something is broken. Its because `white-space: nowrap;`